# 404 when visiting localhost on port 3000 or 3001 (default ports used by BrowserSync)

Tags: php, symfony, gulp, browser-sync

I am trying to implement Gulp into my project. I have succesfully created one task and willing to integrate BrowserSync with it.

Here is my `gulpfile.js`:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    var concat = require('gulp-concat');
    var env = process.env.GULP_ENV;
    var browserSync= require('browser-sync');
    var reload= browserSync.reload;

    gulp.task('js', function () {
        gulp.src([
            'src/**/Resources/public/js/*.js'])
            .pipe(concat('javascript.js'))
            .pipe(gulpif(env == 'prod', uglify()))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'))
            .pipe(reload({stream:true}));
    });

    gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
        browserSync({server:
                    {
                        baseDir: "./"
                    }});

    });

    gulp.task('watch', function()
    {
       gulp.watch('src/**/Resources/public/js/*.js',['js']);

    });

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync','watch']);
```

I am using PHP for the backend (Synfony 2.3). Normally I visit the website on localhost by visiting `localhost/websiteName/web/app_dev.php/hello/SO`. According to the tutorial I have read, BrowserSync is operating under the port 3000 ,but when I do `localhost:3000/websiteName/web/app_dev.php/hello/SO` it gives me a 404.

visiting `localhost:3001` sends me BrowserSync home page, that indicates to me
that local is `http://localhost:3000`!

I am not experienced enough to understand what might be the cause under the hood. Your usual help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run `gulp watch`? Any errors?

Comment: @staypuftman, thank you for your time. When I run `gulp watch` I get no errors. What happens is that Gulp starts,and whenever I do a save in a js file, Gulp effectively catch this change and execute the corresponding task.

Comment: Then you likely have a server error in your local VM. This doesn't look like gulp failing to me. Check nginx or apache conflicts - maybe a `mod_rewrite` rule is broken or `htdocs` or something like that?

Comment: @staypuftman When you said the word `VM` you made me remember a change I have done in the past to my `httpd-conf` and `hosts` files (to be able to visit projects like `project1.dev` and `project2.dev` instead of `localhost/project1/`...). I honnestly implement such things without understanding them. Do you think such changes can bring problems to server?

Comment: Yes, almost certainly your problem is in there I would guess. Local VMs can be a pain - this guide really helped me awhile back if you doing LAMP: https://medium.com/@raureif/os-x-yosemite-how-to-set-up-apache-mysql-and-php-with-homebrew-4bc236d7d9fa#.vharbpcyj

Comment: @staypuftman, man I removed all the stuff related to local VMs, but the problem remains. BTW I am using Windows XAMPP and it is time to swap to LAMP with the docs you provided me with. thanks again

Comment: @staypuftman, well Malcolm provided with a solution, but I thank you anyway for your time and for the conviction you gave me that I should soon change and understand my dev environement better.

Comment: glad I could help somehow! I also learned from malcolm with that answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing it this way:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "localhost/websiteName/web/app_dev.php"
    });
});
```

https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy

Comment: thank you very much sir, without understanding it fully, I am at least happy that is works.

Comment: Easy to understand, just your site is accesible on different address `localhost:3000`, you can now watch changes even in php files and reload browser: `gulp.watch(['src/**/*.php'], [browserSync.reload]);` - Happy Coding!

Comment: It is just that I don't understand the word `proxy`. Thank you for the additional hint.